# My android application is not one of the default application when i scan an nfc tag

Tags: android, nfc

I have a problem with the intent filters.

I want to write an application that could read all the nfc tags available by android and i don't understand why my application is not visible by the system when i scan a tag... Indeed, the system offers me the possibilty to launch the others applications i have installed but not my application.

Here is the my manifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
    android:required="true" />
<application 
...
   <activity
        android:name=".read.ReadActivity"
        android:label="NfcSamples" 
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/filter_nfc" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I precise that I don't want to launch specifics tags but read all the tags availables.

What do I missed ?

Comment: Try adding `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />` to your `TAG_DISCOVERED` `<intent-filter>`.

Comment: I try it but it doesn't change anything...  I don't understand what I missed

Comment: Download the NFC TagInfo app and the AppXplore app from the Play Store. Use AppXplore to examine the manifest of NFC TagInfo, and see what else may differ between your setup and theirs.

Comment: That's the first things I've done and i have the same intent filters than theirs...

<intent-filter
    >
    <action
     android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
     >
    </action>
   </intent-filter>
   <meta-data
    android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
    android:resource="@7F040000"
    >
   </meta-data>
   <intent-filter
    >
    <action
     android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"
     >
    </action>
    <category
     android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
     >
    </category>
   </intent-filter>

Comment: Do you see anything in the logcat? Any relevant errors?

Comment: Nop... no errors... just the "choose application dialog"

Comment: I also try with just 
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            </intent-filter> 
but it doesn't work anymore

Comment: what kind of nfc tag do you scan? On which level Android discovers this tag? If it is `TECH_DISCOVERED` (lowest level) then form my experience file `filter_nfc` might be a problem (the file from documentation must be corrected). Show contents of this file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml of the project that I read/write/authenticate Mifare Classic/Ultralight/Desfire/DesfireEV1 tags:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="nfcapp.app"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"></uses-permission>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="nfcapp.app.NFCAppActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- Handle notes detected from outside our application -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do,  is simply not possible. Android launches the app with the most specific intent filter that matches. So, in general,  there will often be an app with a more specific intent filter (e.g. the complete URL) that matches,  so that app will be started instead of your app.